# Black and white PNG to SVG

Tags: google-maps, svg, imagemagick, png

I have a river/land mask to differentiate land with rivers/lakes. The size of this file is (W)43,200x(H)21,600.

The file is impossible to open as the RAM fills up instantly.  I have split the file into 3600*3600 blocks and they open fine. However I'm trying to plot the file over land in google maps, the system still slows down when overlaying the image.

I'm wondering if there is a way to transfer the 3600*3600 PNG image to SVG, but only create vectors for the boundaries between the black and white colours.  This in theory would decrease the size of the file.

I'm currently trying to make an SVG file, but the file size is roughly 1GB in size. It doesn't load the file in linux (eog), and it doesnt load while overlaying over Google maps.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Cool! Show us an image please.

Comment: What is the filetype of your image?  At the resolution you state, an uncompressed greyscale image would only be about 933MB.  So if your file is over 1GB, then I assume it must be a compressed full colour image.  If so, your first step to making it's size manageable would be to convert it to a black & white two-color bitmap, which would reduce the file to approx 117MB.  If you compress that, then I would expect it to reduce to a fraction of that, likely 20MB or less.  You can then think about using potrace to trace it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your images, you may be able to do this with `potrace` and `ImageMagick`. Let's say your initial image is a `PNG` file like this:

[image]

You can use `ImageMagick` to make that into a `PBM` format image, like `potrace` prefers, and then make that into an `SVG` like this:

```
convert river.png pbm:- | potrace - -s -o river.svg
```

The `SVG` file is around half the size of the `PNG`. If anyone likes looking inside `SVG` files, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="3000.000000pt" height="2000.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 3000.000000 2000.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.11, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2013
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,2000.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M4554 16821 c-3 -3 -114 -6 -247 -7 -395 -4 -437 -5 -467 -14 -17 -5
-32 -5 -34 -1 -5 8 -136 8 -151 -1 -5 -3 -53 -6 -106 -6 -53 0 -113 -5 -135
-11 -21 -5 -76 -11 -121 -13 -46 -1 -83 -5 -83 -8 0 -8 -3 -8 -107 -14 -45 -3
-102 -10 -125 -17 -24 -7 -72 -13 -108 -15 -71 -3 -90 -7 -134 -23 -16 -7 -31
-9 -34 -6 -3 2 -11 0 -19 -6 -10 -9 -13 -8 -13 0 0 7 -4 10 -9 6 -5 -3 -31 -8
...
...
-63 -3 -164 -1 -197 4 -18 3 -35 2 -38 -3 -4 -7 -62 -6 -178 3 -21 1 -41 -1
-43 -5 -2 -3 -39 -4 -82 -1 -129 8 -152 8 -152 1 0 -4 -21 -5 -47 -3 -91 8
-135 10 -139 6z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is awesome man. However the rivers are in white rather than black, how can i change this?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but you can change it to `convert river.png -negate pbm:- ....` if you want to invert black and white.

Comment: wicked, ive managed to do it. The resolution changes from 3600*3600 to 4500*4500. how can i match this?

Comment: Not sure... it is bed-time here in the UK. I will have a look again in the morning. What is the original size of your image and can you post it? Try looking at the help pages for `potrace`. Also, are you on Mac OS X, Linu or Windows? Can you run `identify -verbose YourRiverFile.png` and `identify -verbose YourSVGFile.svg` and paste the results into your question - `not as a Comment` but actually by clicking `edit` under your question. Thanks.