# PNG images to SVG

Tags: svg, png

I want to make a responsive website. Part of that is to enhance my graphics. I have a few PNG flat icons that I would like to convert to SVG but I have no knowledge about Illustrator or any other SVG editor. I've tried an online service called vector magic, but the results are not what I need.

What is the best way to convert my images to SVG?

Comment: Have a look at, and maybe vote for :-) my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748282/black-and-white-png-to-svg/28749734#28749734  Or maybe post some sample images so I, and other folks, can help you better...

Comment: "The best way" is opiniated, and also kind of dependent on what you hope to achieve. If you want the exact *pixels* converted to *rectangles*, then you have exactly the same image in vector format. However, then there is no quality gain. Best practice would be to draw your images from scratch, as no software in the world can guess what detail (which can be as small as a single pixel!) is important and what is not, and what edge should be converted to a slanted straight line, or a curve, or stair-case steps.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry for the long wait. You can see 3 circle icons at http://bike-sharing.org/ . I want to convert those. How would I best do it? I can convert the 2 easy ones by just drawing the shapes in notepad, but the bicycle is hard to do.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/chiggum/mindthegap with noisy switch (-z) if the input image has blended colors and change the number of desired colors in output using (-n <num>).

Answer (score 0):

You should try Illustrator to vectorize your images (there is a function to do this). There will never be a perfect result, so you'll have to correct imperfections.

Here is a [link](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/vectorize-illustrator-45968.html) that explains how to do this. You'll have then to save your image in "save as" and change the ai filename (for illustrator) to svg.